# How to remove a row of a Dataframe if more than one value is zero?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analyzing data from an accelerator. It returns acceleration in the x, y, and z directions as well as a timestamp. These values are stored in a Pandas DataFrame. Sometimes the accelerator returns bad data. In this case, at least two of the values (x, y, or z) will be zero. How do I find and remove rows from a dataframe where any two values are zero?

Comment: Please post sample data

Comment: Are x, y & z each in separate column?

Comment: Have you tried something like `df.loc[((df['x'] == 0) + (df['y'] == 0) + (df['z'] == 0)) <= 1]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below method

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'timestamp': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'x': [1, 0, 0, 5],
        'y': [0, 2, 3, 0],
        'z': [4, 5, 0, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Filter rows where at least two values are zero
filtered_df = df[(df[['x', 'y', 'z']] == 0).sum(axis=1) < 2]

print(filtered_df)
```